# How can we identify particular signal is a high speed signals?

Tags: pcb

How can we identify or determine a signal is a high speed signal?

Is there any way to find out or calculation mechanism available to find HSS? (it may calculated from Frequency ranges or special characteristics or calculations from transmission line or calculated from Data rate speed, etc...)

Comment: This is a rather broad question. Do you have a special case which you'd like to measure? What frequency ranges would you like to detect?

Comment: What's HSS? Could you please spell it out? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to classify your signal, or trying to find out what signal is on the _unknown_  board? Please, edit the question more specific to your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A signal is usually considered high speed requiring [Transmission Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line) methods if the *length of the signal track is long compared with the highest frequency of interest in the signal*.

The same may be said of any medium that can carry electromagnetic radiation.

For FR4, the velocity of wavefront propagation is about 160 picoseconds per inch for surface tracks, and closer to 175 picoseconds per inch for internal layers. I am not going to derive this here; suffice to say it is a well known formula that may be found with a simple search. Try "signal velocity vs relative permittivity".

If you have a signal that has 10% or more of the rise or fall time along the length of track, you should treat it as a high speed transmission line.

To put a number on that, many I/O buffers available on modern processors have 250 picosecond rise and fall times; if they drive a track longer than 0.15 inch, they should be considered transmission lines.

As noted, this is a very broad question; if you have a specific issue you are trying to understand, then ask a new question more tightly focused.

HTH

Edit: Added note about the breadth of the subject.

This subject can take decades to master fully. What I have written above is simply an accepted definition of what constitutes a high-speed line.

Comment: i just want the basic understaning so your answer helps me to study indetph about it. thanks